# How to find the process ID of a running scheduled task?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I can determine running tasks with:

```
$TaskService    = new-object -ComObject('Schedule.Service')
$TaskService.connect()
$TaskFolder = $TaskService.GetFolder('\')
$TaskFolder.gettasks(1) | ? {$_.state -eq 4}
```

Is there any way to identify the process IDs of those tasks if they start the same program (i.e. process name) as other existing processes?

My goal is a PowerShell script started from a scheduled task that can identify which scheduled task it is running under.  I can easily determine the PoSh processID with `$PID`, but I don't know how to link that to a particular scheduled task.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan on using this information? What does knowing the PID do for you?

Comment: I have a script that is started by several different scheduled tasks with different triggers.  In some situations, I want the script to identify which scheduled task from which it was born.

Comment: I would change the script and the tasks so that they launch the script with parameters that identify the triggers...

Comment: You could just add a param to the script that you can specify which task started it? Something simple like `-StartedFrom SchedTask1`

Comment: Command-line arguments seem like a better solution to your problem. That said, it's not difficult to get the PID of a task. For a list of all running tasks, the [task service interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832) has a `GetRunningTasks` method. OTOH, for a particular folder, loop over the tasks and call `GetInstances` on each task. In either case, you get a collection of running tasks. A running task has properties for its `Name`, `Path`, `CurrentAction`, and `EnginePID`. The latter is the PID of the process that's running the task.

Comment: @eryksun That is an answer. You should write it up as such.

Comment: Hmm perhaps there is more to it if the tasks are all running at the same time. Then you would not know which one is which.

Comment: I'm not having a problem identifying running tasks, but I don't see how to get the PID.  The code in the OP does not return an `EnginePID` property.  Could you give some example (PoSh) code to get the `EnginePID`?

Comment: `$TaskService.GetRunningTasks(0)` will show all that you have access to see as per [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)

Comment: @Matt Doh! That's really simple.  Thanks for spelling it out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you have this running in the script that is fired as an action. It will get the task path assuming it can be found by the RunningTasks COM object method

```
# Initiate a COM object and connect
$TaskService = New-Object -ComObject('Schedule.Service')
$TaskService.Connect()

# Query for currently running tasks 
# 0 - the user is permitted to see. 
# 1 - 0 + Hidden
$runningTasks = $TaskService.GetRunningTasks(0)

# Get the task associated to a certain PID
$runningTasks | Where-Object{$_.EnginePID -eq $PID} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

Credit goes to [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260650/how-to-find-the-process-id-of-a-running-scheduled-task?noredirect=1#comment85528932_49260650) for pointing out the method and linking to the [ITaskService interface on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832)

---

There is something to be said about the other suggestion of just telling your script what is running from via an extra parameter. That way you don't have to worry about a COM dependency.

```
param(
  [string]$SuperImportantString,
  [int]$NumberofBagels,
  [string]$TaskInitiated
)

Set-Content -Path $file -Value "I'm running from $TaskInitiated"
```

Yes, this does make it more manual but you would have ultimate control over the text and such used and not have to worry about multiple tasks running from the same PID.

Comment: Thanks for formally writing this answer, and thanks to @eryksun for the initial info.

Comment: I have since discovered that the first answer works for the SYSTEM or Admin account, but `GetRunningTasks(1)` called by an unprivileged user doesn't return all of that user's tasks.  The running process is identified as belonging to the user and can be seen by the user, but the running tasks list (checked by the user) is conspicuously absent of the task with that ID.  An admin can see the running task of the user.  This must be a bug in the scheduling service API.  Why else would a user be prevented from seeing their own running tasks?

Comment: More detail: `GetRunningTasks(1)` works fine if the user created the task, but not if the task was assigned to the user by an admin.  So even though the task runs as the user, the user can't see (through the schedule service) that it is running.  In Win10, tasks appear to be entirely stored in the registry (much of the information in binary) and are resistant to changes.  The permissions on user-created tasks and admin-created tasks are the same.  It's not clear what restricts users from seeing tasks they didn't create.

Comment: Update:  Apparently, visibility of a task for both the Task Scheduler GUI and a TaskService object (e.g. the `GetRunningTasks(1)` method) is determined by the `Author` property.  Creating a task as Admin that runs as a user doesn't allow the user to see it.  Importing a task as Admin with the `Author` set to the user **or a group the user is a member of** does allow the user(s) to see the task in both the GUI and a scripted TaskService object.  The unprivileged user does not have rights to delete the task however.  ACLs on the Tasks are still a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it tells me exactly which task started the script:

```
$EventFilter = @{ 
              Logname      = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
              ProviderName = "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler"
              Id           = 129
              Data         = "$PID"
           }

$ThisProcessEvent = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $EventFilter -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$EventXML = [xml]$ThisProcessEvent.toxml()

$TaskFullName = $eventxml.event.eventdata.data | ? {$_.name -eq 'taskname'} |select -ExpandProperty "#text"
```

Comment: This answer (mostly) works as long as users have permission to access the event logs.  Unfortunately, the event log might slightly lag the process itself and no event is returned.  The only way (I know of) around that is a very ugly `start-sleep` for a few seconds before looking for the event.